# Startup Disk Creator wont let me pick my iso file

Tags: 12.04, startup-disk-creator

Ive recently upgraded to 13.10 and its just not for me, so what i want to do is downgrade back to 12.04(which i know works perfect for me). I downloaded my 12.04 amd iso but alas, it wont let me pick my iso file, usually the iso is already set, as a matter of fact. It just shows an empty bar. Im not sure what to do. Semi-novice.

[image]

Comment: Did you push the button labeled "Other"?

Comment: I did indeed, then i went and selected the iso i wanted and it reverted back to the image you (now) see above.

Comment: your usb disk was not mounted at all.Mount your usb drive,format it to fat32 filesystem and then open startup disk creator.

Comment: It's not about the usb disk, but the ISO. I don't know what is going there, but as a workaround you use UNetBooting, another live-usb from ISO creator.

Comment: No it was about the usb, it did the same thing whilst the usb was mounted. Avinash solved my problem. All i had to do was format the usb. I had simply deleted the files from 13.10 instead of formatting. Im not happily on my way to 12.04. Thanks guys.

Comment: WAIT! ![This](http://imgur.com/QHYKNYQ) is a thing now. @Avinash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your usb disk was not mounted at all.Mount your usb drive,format it to fat32 filesystem and then open startup disk creator.

Now your usb drive was automatically detected and you can able to choose the iso.

Comment: why startup diskcreator was closed?

Comment: close the starup disk creator,reinsert the formatted usb then open the application and then select the other option to choose the ubuntu iso file.

Comment: WAIT! [This](http://imgur.com/QHYKNYQ) is a thing now. Could you help with this or should i ask another question involving this? @Avinash

Comment: try the above comment.

Comment: Alright, it did it again.

Comment: try unetbootin.

Comment: Interesting, maybe i got a bad version of sdc. It worked in unetbootin. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to accept. I was at a friends house for a few days.